# STM32L0xx: Get the clock speed

Tags: stm32, stm32l152, libopencm3

For the life of me, I cannot find a way to get the clock speed for STM32L0 chips in libopencm3. There's got to be a way, right?

- In STM32Cube, there's the `SystemCoreClock` variable.
- In ChibiOs, there's the `STM32_SYSCLK` variable.

Is there no variable or function to get this value in libopencm3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far the closest thing I've found to a solution is the `rcc_ahb_frequency` variable, which is set to the Advanced High-performance Bus frequency. This is usually the same as the clock speed, but *can* be given a clock divider.

Also, it looks like this is only defined if the clock is configured via the `rcc_clock_setup_pll` method.